# Drop down/CSS inquiry

Tags: html, css, menu, drop-down-menu

I have an unordered list set up for a hover/dropdown menu. I have the structure set up perfectly as far as the code. The ul and li structure is all set. I am wondering if anyone can tell me the css structure/style to get it to work...aka hover over the main button and have the other links drop down. I need to know how to do that as well as style them, and how to calculate the number(px,zindex, etc.) to be proportionate with sizes of my buttons and have everything line up properly

Comment: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dropdowns/
http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/
Just google suckerfish and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chetan has it in his comment, but the best introduction to basic CSS only dropdowns is:

[A List Apart: Articles: Suckerfish Dropdowns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dropdowns/)